# NSTableView showing last object in every row

Tags: swift, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. I have a very simple app with a class `Person`, an `NSTableView` and an `NSArrayController` "PersonController".

Person:

```
class Person: NSObject {
    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""
}
```

PersonController:

- Added outlet to ViewController
- Attributes Inspector > Object Controller > Class Name = Person

TableView:

- Attributes Inspector > Table View > Content Mode = Cell based
- 1st Table Column bound to Person Controller with Controller Key: arrangedObjects and Model key path: firstName
- 2nd Table Column bound to Person Controller with Controller Key: arrangedObjects and Model key path: lastName

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var personController: NSArrayController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let person = Person()
        var people = [Person]()
        person.firstName = "John"
        person.lastName = "Snow"
        people.append(person)
        person.firstName = "Kate"
        person.lastName = "Dawson"
        people.append(person)
        person.firstName = "Tom"
        person.lastName = "Anderson"
        people.append(person)
        personController.addObjects(people)
    }
    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {}
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I've read many SO posts and a ton of tutorials etc and from what I can tell I'm doing it correctly but I can't for the life of me get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one `Person` object. When you append it to the array, that doesn't make a copy. The array just contains a reference to that one object. You're appending the same object three times, so the array contains three references to that one object.

Each time you change that one `Person`'s `firstName` and `lastName`, you're changing that one object's properties. So, at each index of the array, the table finds that one object with the last values set for its name properties.

You need to create three separate `Person` objects.

As a separate matter, you need to mark the properties of `Person` as `dynamic` if you want them to be Key-Value-Observing-compliant and thus Bindings-compatible.

Comment: Face palm!! I can't believe I wasted so much time on that! Thanks mate!